# Filter JPA repository by multiple optional parameters

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple REST service that returns user profile entity that has about 20 fields.

I need to implement a functionality to filter the data where last name is required but all other fields (first name, age, city, state, zip, etc. ) are optional.

Is there a way to do it using `JpaRepository` without creating a lot of `if`/`else` statements for every single combination of patamenters?

Answer (score 3):

It is a use case for [JPA criteria](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html) (available since JPA2).
In indeed as you want to write a dynamic query, above all, you don't want to hard-coded `JPQL` queries for each combination and you don't want concatenating chunks of `JPQL` either as this is error-prone and not checked at compile time.

Note that in any case (`Criteria` or `JPQL`) you should check for each possible option if the client has specified it to be able to take them into consideration in the query build.

Now, as you implement the `JPARepository` interface, you have two ways :

- using `List<T> findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec);` provided by the `JpaSpecificationExecutor` interface that you can also implement in your custom repository.
- Enrich the `JPARepository` with your own interface that defines a method `findAll()` and that takes as parameter an object containing values for the research.
   Then create a concrete class to implement  `JPARepository`.
  You would have so the ability to inject the `EntityManager` and to use the `Criteria` API.

Comment: I could do it using Specificaiton. One small point for those who try using specification, most solutions use MetaModel Classes(ClassName_), it can be skipped by just giving field name in string.

Answer (score 3):

JpaRepository interface also implements *QueryByExampleExecutor* interface which provides findAll method for getting data using Query by Example (QBE) technique. That method would be really applicable for your scenario and is actually ideal when entity has a lot of fields and you want user to be able to filter entities by some of them.

Let's say the entity is *Person* and you want to create endpoint for fetching persons whose properties are equal to the ones which are specified. That could be accomplished with the following code:

*Entity class:*

```java
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Integer age;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zipCode;
}
```

*Controller class:*

```java
@Controller
public class PersonController {
    private PersonService service;
    private PersonController(PersonService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Person> getMatchingPersons(@RequestBody Person personFilter) {
        return service.findMatchingPersons(personFilter);
    }
}
```

*Service class:*

```java
@Service
public class PersonService {
    private PersonRepository repository;
    private PersonService(PersonRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public List<Person> getMatchingPersons(Person personFilter) {
        return repository.findAll(Example.of(personFilter));
    }
}
```

*Repository class:*

```java
@Repository
public class PersonRepository implements JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

- It's always best to return a DTO representation of an entity in the
  REST response.
- In your DTO, you can only map required fields from an entity and
  ignore other optional parameters.

Check this out http://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application